# before="Mage_Adminhtml" after="Mage_Adminhtml"

Tags: admin, configuration

I have been receiving a 404 on my admin module, after a lot of trouble shooting I realised it was something to do with this block of code in the config.xml file

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <some_module>Some_Module_Adminhtml</some_module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

To fix the 404 I changed it to this

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <some_module after="Mage_Adminhtml">Some_Module_Adminhtml</some_module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

This worked but I wanted to understand it.

I tried adding `before="Mage_Adminhtml"` and expected to receive a 404, instead it worked again.

- Why do I need to add a before or after for my page to load? (I'm assuming it loads before or after a core module and it would be used for when one of my module is dependant on one of the core module)

I have always assumed that the admin modules followed the same loading as any other module i.e. local, community, mage (this track of thought had me assuming that `before="Mage_Adminhtml"` would be the default behaviour).

I have looked through `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin` to try and get my answers but couldn't find it and can't think where else to look

Comment: check this http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited

Answer (score 6):

This `before` and `after` defines whether the controller should be looked up in Mage_Adminhtml first or in your module.

If your Controller is unique, then it doesn't matter what you define.

If you change an existing route, like checkout_cart_add -> `Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction`, then your action is called, when you use `before` and the magento original if you use `after`